# gnu parallel how to use with ffmpeg

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, gnu-parallel

I have folder that contains some mp4 files I want to extract images from each of them in parallel and save it as:

filename_number.bmp

where filename is the input filename

how to do that using parallel and ffmpeg

Answer (score 8):

I'm using the example from your previous question to use as an example for GNU parallel

```
ls *.mp4 | parallel ffmpeg -i {} fr1/{.}_%d.jpg -hide_banner
```

I can adjust the answer if this is not quite what you want. The “{}” gets replaced by GNU parallel with the whole file name, and “{.}” gets replaced by the file name with the last segment, separated by periods, removed.

Comment: @mark - make sure and select this as the accepted answer if it is

Comment: Is "parallel" the same as "xargs -P" ?

Comment: No. It is GNU Parallel. xargs -P does not support dynamically computing the number of cores and does not support {.}.